# El resultado me da "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript, me costó mucho llegar a armar éste código y que no me diera error. Ahora casi lo logro pero me da "undefined". Me podrian ayudar a redondearlo? pienso que el problema esta en conectar bien ambas funciones pero no sé como hacerlo.
El ejercicio consiste en que el usuario ingresa una serie de numeros en inputs en el html (a todos les puse la misma clase y aca en el .js los guardo como un array) y le tengo que devolver la mediana de esa lista de números.
Este es el resultado que me da:

La mediana es de: undefined

```
function onclickButtonCalcularMediana(){
    let array = [];

    let inputNumeros = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumeros"); 

    array.push(inputNumeros.value);
    
    let arrayOrdenado = array.sort( (elem1, elem2) =>  elem1 - elem2 );

    let mediana = calcularMediana(arrayOrdenado);

    const inputResultado = document.getElementById("inputResultado");
    inputResultado.innerText = "La mediana es de: " + mediana;
    
};



function calcularMediana(arrayOrdenado){
    function esPar(arrayOrdenado) {
        if (arrayOrdenado.length % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    let mediana = 0;

    if (esPar(arrayOrdenado.length)) {
        const elemento1 = arrayOrdenado[arrayOrdenado.length /2 - 1];
        const elemento2 = arrayOrdenado [arrayOrdenado.length / 2];
    
        mediana = (elemento1 + elemento2) / 2;
        return mediana;   
    } else {
        mediana = arrayOrdenado[arrayOrdenado.length / 2];  
        return mediana;
    }    
};
```

Comment: deberias poner el html. Si recibes los numeros a traves de inputs las funciones deberian ser onChange() en vez de onClick() para tomar el value

Comment: La asignación `arrayLleno = array.push` es incorrecta. El método `push` devuelve `undefined`, aunque modifica únicamente a `array`.

Comment: @hernánGarcia osea que si uso el onChange() me ahorro el tener que poner ".value" luego?

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto al comentario, primero que nada procura no usar funciones inline (las que van en el HTML)

Una forma sencilla de captar el cambio en un input es asi:

```js
 document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = `Ingresaste: ${e.target.value}`
  e.target.value = null;
 })
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa un texto">
 <br><br>
 <div></div>
```

al input le coloco un listener para que tome el evento change (cuando ingresas texto y das a enter o tab) el parametro "e" tomo el evento (que elemento HTML lo disparo). Luego selecciono el div y le coloco en su interior lo que trae el value del input (e.target.value)

**AMPLIADO**

Hacerlo con la funcion onchange inline seria asi:

```js
function algo(elem){
  alert("Has ingresado: " + elem.value);
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="algo(this)" placeholder="Escribe algo">
```

para tomar el evento desde una funcion inline debes pasar como argumento THIS, this hace, en este caso, referencia al elemento que disparo el evento.

Comment: hola! en realidad estoy aprendiendo y en el curso aún no nos enselaron querys. Y no estoy segura a que te referis con lo de inline.. solo lo conozco el contexto de css

Comment: funciones inline es cuando directamente en la etiqueta html pones el llamado a la funcion: <div onclick="miFuncion()">mi div</div>. Si te estan enseñanado de seguro luego te diran que no es buena practica, como tampoco lo es poner el css inline (style=".....")

Comment: lo de no poner el css inline lo sabia. lo otro no! de hecho el profesor lo esta haciendo de esa manera! supongo (espero) que ya llegará a explicarlo bien y por ahora lo este usando sólo de parche... gracias por el dato!

Comment: ahi te puse algo mas ya que te estan enseñando con funciones inline

Comment: muchas gracias!